# when user want to login : AXIOS ERROR: [Error: Request failed with status code 401] BAD_REQUEST

Tags: reactjs, react-native, docker-compose, axios, bad-request

i have a react native app and want to login EXISTING USER IN DATABASE with username and password for get the accesstoken and refreshtoken from api/login. but i get 401 error .

error in docker log:

```
    app_1       | 2022-06-23 20:56:55.997 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.r.hamsafar
.service.UsersServiceImpl    : User Not Found In Database
app_1       | Hibernate:
app_1       |     select
app_1       |         users0_.id as id1_1_,
app_1       |         users0_.activation_code as activati2_1_,
app_1       |         users0_.active as active3_1_,
app_1       |         users0_.disabled as disabled4_1_,
app_1       |         users0_.failed_try_count as failed_t5_1_,
app_1       |         users0_.family as family6_1_,
app_1       |         users0_.lock_time as lock_tim7_1_,
app_1       |         users0_.name as name8_1_,
app_1       |         users0_.national_code as national9_1_,
app_1       |         users0_.password as passwor10_1_,
app_1       |         users0_.sms_time as sms_tim11_1_,
app_1       |         users0_.username as usernam12_1_
app_1       |     from
app_1       |         users users0_
app_1       |     where
app_1       |         users0_.username=?
```

This is while the user is in the database and it works with the same username and password correctly and without error in postman.

axios codes:

```
 var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('username', '0123456789');
  formData.append('password', '0123456789');
  axios.post(
    'http://1.2.3.4:5555/api/login'
    , { formData })
    .then(response => {
          console.log("RESPONSE RECEIVED: ", response);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log("AXIOS ERROR: ", err);
        })
```

please help me

Comment: 401 means you're doing something wrong when making the request or making it in a way that the server doesn't expect. There's no information provided about the backend or what it expects. I would suggest looking through the documentation for the login again

Comment: 401 is "Unauthorized". 400 is the typical "Bad Request" response. But since it works in postman, it's safe to assume that the 401 might be an underlying 400

Comment: @Fredrik Schön : i see "Unauthorized"  in error log

Comment: @Abir Taheer : 
cache-control →no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
connection →keep-alive
content-length →842
content-type →application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1
date →Thu, 23 Jun 2022 21:50:59 GMT
expires →0
keep-alive →timeout=20
pragma →no-cache
x-content-type-options →nosniff
x-frame-options →DENY
x-xss-protection →1; mode=block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/users/6730803/fredrik-sch%c3%b6n

https://stackoverflow.com/users/10237430/abir-taheer

i solved my problem with used the username and password in  url like this:

'http://1.2.3.4:5555/api/login?username='0123456789'&password='0123456789''

thank you from :

https://stackoverflow.com/users/6730803/fredrik-sch%c3%b6n

&

https://stackoverflow.com/users/10237430/abir-taheer

&

https://stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

Often these types of error is because your server expects a content-type header, in order to understand how to parse the request body (your form in this case).

Look closely at the request from Postman that works, what does it have that you're omitting in your code?

If you've added form data, I believe postman automatically adds the Content-Type header for the appropriate data you've added.

Try editing your code to something like this (removed wrapping formData in an object & added multipart/form-data content-type header):

```js
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('username', '0123456789');
formData.append('password', '0123456789');

axios.post('http://1.2.3.4:5555/api/login', formData, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    }
  })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log('RESPONSE RECEIVED: ', response);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('AXIOS ERROR: ', err);
  });
```

---

Update based on comment revealing Postman using Content-Type application/json:

Try changing header & body to json instead, if that's what your server expects & works in postman:

```js
const data = { username: '0123456789', password: '0123456789' };

axios.post('http://1.2.3.4:5555/api/login', data, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
  })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log('RESPONSE RECEIVED: ', response);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('AXIOS ERROR: ', err);
  });
```

Comment: header config from postman:    cache-control →no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
connection →keep-alive
content-length →842
content-type →application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1
date →Thu, 23 Jun 2022 21:50:59 GMT
expires →0
keep-alive →timeout=20
pragma →no-cache
x-content-type-options →nosniff
x-frame-options →DENY
x-xss-protection →1; mode=block

Comment: I tried but I still have the some error    401

Comment: I see, then it looks like your server expects json, instead of form-data: try `"Content-Type": "application/json"` instead!

Comment: and change the body accordingly... instead for new FormData(), just add the object: `const data = { username: '123456789', password: '0123456789' }` instead of the formData variable

Comment: tested const data and still issues error 401

Comment: Interesting, if postman works but not the code it means there is another difference between the postman and the code. Maybe the backend server has IP whitelisting, so your application gets Unauthorized (401) and your postman works because your computer is allowed but not wherever your container is running..?